# Postgres data to csv with force quotes

Tags: postgresql, talend

I am trying to fetch postgres table data into CSV by using below query, be default it is giving '|' as delimiter, but in table data there are multiple delimiters, so i want to fetch the data by using "" as delimiter or force_quote

```
psql -h host -p port -U user -d dbname --no-align -c "SELECT * from sample" > D:\sample.csv
```

can any one pull me out from this issue..thanks in advance

Comment: Use `\copy`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY

Comment: see Options list @ https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 2):

as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested, you can do it with smth like:

```
psql -h host -p port -U user -d dbname --no-align -c "\copy (select * from sample) to stdout with (format csv, force_quote *, quote \$\$'\$\$)" > D:\sample.csv
```

or reducing the code to a neater version:

```
psql -h host -p port -U user -d dbname --no-align -c "\copy sample to 'D:\sample.csv' with (format csv, force_quote *, quote \$\$'\$\$)" >
```

of course you can change `\$\$'\$\$` to `''''` if you find it any more readable...

Comment: `psql -h host -p port -U user -d dbname --no-align -c "\Copy sample TO 'D:\sample.csv' WITH (DELIMITER ';', FORCE_QUOTE *, QUOTE '\"', FORMAT CSV, HEADER)`

Answer (score 0):

Do a job talend like :

```
tpostgresinput -> tmap -> tfiledelimitedOutput
```

And put your "Select" condition in the query in the tpostgres input.

Comment: can u please tell me how to move postgres data to s3 without changing timestamp format..i.e actuall timestamp:07 09 2016 22:22:34 Changed timestamp:07 sep 2016 22:22:34..